# copy Docker CACHE to another host

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm moving between datacenters and want to move a host used for Docker **builds** (not a repository) to another server. This host is used to build custom (relatively large, internally used) images from Dockerfiles.

I've tried with `docker save` and `docker load`, which copied all the images and tags listed by `docker images`. However, when I run `docker build` on my Dockerfiles, then everything gets rebuilt from scratch, which is problematic.

I guess that by using `docker load`, Docker has lost the relationship between the `Dockerfile` and the resulting images.

How can I restore this relationship? Copy some cache?

I have full access to both the old and the new host.